# Magento Catalog Price Rules "conditions" and Shopping Cart Rules "conditions" not appearing in admin panel

Tags: magento

Both Catalog Price Rules "conditions" and Shopping Cart Rules "conditions" are not appearing in the Magento Admin panel after a migration.  Magento 1.8.1.  There was an extension (amasty) that was installed previously.

Comment: Questions about Magento should be asked on [magento.se]

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is an error. You can find it in the `var/log/exception.log` file or `var/log/system.log`

Try to also set developer mode ON  and display_errors ON to see it at the screen.

I also advice to disable all local / community modules in the `app/etc/modules` to see if it is core issue or it's en extension issue.